# how to append .csv files in a folder ( side by side with 2 columns gap)

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending 10 CSV file in a folder, I want to merge them vertically not horizontally, how can I do that

this is the format I am looking for

```
[df1  df2  df3 ......... df10]
```

**but  Not like this**

```
[

df1
df2
...
df10

]
```

The code

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r' ' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []
```

this is the code i am trying

```
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame1 = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame1.to_csv('name of 'folder )
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: Try the other axis: `pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I can merge horizontally but not vertically, i will try this

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to just give code as that might have errors as I am a newbie in Python, but I would help with the step-by-step process of doing this. You need to:

- Create ten dataframes with the ten csv files
- Transpose them using the ".T" function(rows become columns and vice-versa). This would
  be a lot easier if you just write a simple function for that.
- Convert dataframes to csv
  df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',') #Seperator can be anything you want
- Merge them with glob or glob2
- Convert to dataframe again
- Transpose back using the .T function

Comment: Then please upvote the post. It'd help a lot as I'm still below 20 reputation.Thanks!